# cfimage writetobrowser throwing error on CF10

Tags: coldfusion, osx-mavericks, coldfusion-10

I get the following error with `<cfimage action="writeToBrowser"` on a Mac Mavericks CF10 machine:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException`

I've googled extensively and only came up with one person with a similar problem.

http://qiita.com/cubdesign/items/c5cc0435cb6e928fd3b5

It's in Japanese but translated with Google he says he rolled back to java 1.6.0_65.jdk. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find that particular java version on Oracle's site.

I tried rolling the jdk to 1.6.0_45 but then CF10 wouldn't start.

My machine is set up with java 1.7.0_55.jdk and the latest Mavericks patch from Adobe has been applied to the CF server (update 13).

**Update:**
Submitted [Bug Report #3759721](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3759721) for this issue.

**Update Fixed:**

Credit goes to Leigh (see comments below).

It seems that the Mavericks update wiped the JVM in the /System/Library/Java folder. Unfortunately, it looks like Adobe still has an issue with any version of the jdk above 1.6

Download and install the `dmg` file on this page: [Java for OS X 2013-005](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: (Edit) Does it occur with *all* images or only some?  I am not running Mac, but did you try the link he posted for the jvm? Just swap out the locale:  http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US . It is worth trying, though dropping down to an older version may not be the best solution for the long term.

Comment: @Leigh It occurs with any image I try to write to browser. I've chased down the links looking for java 1.6_65.jdk but can't seem to find it.

Comment: The version in the post is 1.6.0_65. (Might make a difference in search terms). Did you try the download in the link above? I did not do much beyond clicking it, but it seems to start a download ...

Comment: Apparently they stopped posting updates: [Java SE 6 End of Public Updates Notice](http://java.com/en/download/faq/other_jreversions.xml). No wonder you could not find it.

Comment: Please prepare a reproducible test case and submit to https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: @Henry submitted bug to Adobe. Thanks.

Comment: Link to bug: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3759721

Comment: *I've chased down the links* Just to clarify, the one I posted did not work either? ie http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: @Leigh I clicked all through that following multiple links and none lead me to the 1.6.0_65.jdk file.

Comment: @jk. Bummer. I thought the downloaded .dmg file might contain the jdk.

Comment: @Leigh That worked. I now have two JVM's on my workstation. The computer itself is using 1.7. It seems that the Mavericks update wiped the JVM in the /System/Library/Java folder. Unfortunately, it looks like Adobe still has an issue with any version of the jdk above 1.6.

Comment: @jk. (Edit) May want to write that up as a separate "answer", so it is easier to spot. Plus, folks can vote on it too. (You are the one that figured it all out. I just found a link ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

Credit goes to Leigh (see comments below question).

It seems that the Mavericks update wiped the JVM in the /System/Library/Java folder. Unfortunately, it looks like Adobe still has an issue with any version of the jdk above 1.6. See [Bug Report #3759721](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3759721).

Download and install the `dmg` file on this page for the time being: [Java for OS X 2013-005](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: I installed this JDK on Yosemite 10.10.1 and told CF11 to use it (its jvm.config); but it won't even start. Adobe really needs to fix this.

Comment: Well found this question for the second time :/